# Error with a negative offset

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to use the following code to find a value that is not a date and not an empty cell, and copy that value to 6 rows up and 4 rows right to the originally located value with an offset.

Here is my code:

```
 Sub copy_value()
 Dim Srchcust As Range, cust As Range
 Set Srchcust = Range("C:C")
 For Each cust In Srchcust
     If Not IsEmpty(cust) And Not IsDate(cust) Then
         cust.Offset(-6, 4).Value = cust.Value
     End If
 Next cust
 End Sub
```

For some reason, if the offset is set to a negative number, it gives me an error 1004, but as soon as I change -6 to 0, it works, but I need the value to be copied 6 rows above the value's current location.

I would appreciate anyone's help you can let me know what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: What do you expect to happen when `cust` is set to cells C1 ... C6?

Comment: Thanks, had a brainfreeze. Modified the range and that worked.

Comment: And once you fix that, the For loop will loop over 1000000+ rows = very slow and not necessary

Comment: @user3839044 further to Chris's comment, you can check how many loops you'll be running by adding a line just before your `For` statement: `MsgBox Srchcust.Cells.Count` and then run your code like normal.  It will probably tell you that loop is about to run [1,048,576 times](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3).

Comment: I see you found a solution - please post one so future googlers and stack explorers can orient themselves better

Comment: You can reduce loop count by `Set Srchcust = Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange,Range("C:C"))`. Please replace `ActiveSheet` with your Worksheet.

Comment: Yes, I did figure out the solution after  chris neilsen's and ashleedawg's comments and I did also modify the range to prevent too many loops - in fact my code is very similar to the one below. Looks like the solution has been posted below as well, so that works out. Thank you all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is few issues with your code.

First, the error - it happens, when you try reference a cell, that doesn't exist. You can address cells in worksheet with pair of **positive** integers, like `Cells(1, 1)` (`A1` cell), `Cells(3, 4)` (`D3` cell), etc.

When you use offset, it's like you are subtracting particular coordinates. When you try to offset by pair `-1, -1` from cell B2 (`Cells(2, 2)`) you'll get `A` cell (`Cells(1, 1)`) due to `2-1=1`. When you try to do offset by `-6, 4` and loop throguh `C` column, what happens in cells from C1 through C6? Then, for example, one of the coordinates would be `1-6=-5`, which cannot be, thus the error.

Another issue, you loop through whole `C` column! It's not necessary and inefficient! You should find last row of that column with this code:

```
Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
```

Then limit your range by defining it like:

```
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("C1:C" & lastRow)
'or you should do like this, it won't give you error
'Set rng = Range("C7:C" & lastRow)
```

Comment: Thank you, I did actually figure out already thanks to the comments above and my code is very similar to yours as well, so thank you for posting the answer.